# Is it possible to delete ArcGIS imageserver using a script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-image-server

I have an app that allows users to upload TIFF files so that an ImageServer is created in ArcGIS 10.5 Server. However, I don't want to keep the images over a day.

Is there a way of automatically removing an image service using ArcPy?

The code below does not work as it seems to be designed for Desktop:

```
arcpy.Delete_management(url)
```

The same question is asked in Esri community [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/210201-how-to-delete-or-overwrite-image-service) and [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/183153-deleting-a-service-definition) with no answer.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You do need to use the correct operation (REST API). You have your choice of frameworks and languages; though Python is an option, it's not an ArcPy function.

Comment: That is good to know. Could you post the python code that will work as answer?

Comment: My code to do this is ~150 LOC, doesn't handle HTTPS well, and is not on my phone. Oh, and was cobbled from samples from before the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/) was released. You really ought to be researching that before rolling your own.

Comment: You mean your code cost 150k dollars?

Comment: Lines Of Code. It cost my client way more to assemble than $150.

Comment: That is a lot of code. Is the code publicly accessible?

Comment: It came from half a dozen public sources, but I'm not comfortable sharing such a kludged, semi-functional mess. No one really wants to use urllib2 pass JSON back and forth to an AGS host via HTTPS socket calls when a library exists to manage the process. Try the ArcGIS API first.

Comment: @Vince it looks like ArcGIS API for Python is for ArcGIS portal and ArcGIS online only? I got  this error https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a code to publish service from [the Esri website](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/windows/example-publish-a-service-with-detailed-parameters.htm). The code below uses python to delete a service by name. 
The requests module works well with no errors while I faced problems when using `httplib`, `urlopen`, and `urllib2` to send the request.

```
import requests

def delete_service(service_name):
    username = 'name'
    password = 'pass'
    serverPort = 443
    serverName = 'mydomain'
    # getToken() code is available in the link above. 
    token = getToken(username, password, serverName)
    if token == "":
        print "Could not generate a token with the username and password provided."
        return
    deleteServiceURL = "https://mydomain.com/arcgis/admin/" \
                       "services/myfolder/{}/ImageServer/delete".format(
        service_name)

    params = urllib.urlencode({'token': token, 'f': 'json'})
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               "Accept": "text/plain"}
    response = requests.post(deleteServiceURL, params=params, headers=headers)
    # Connect to URL and post parameters, only post allowed for service creation
    if (response.status_code != 200):
        # httpConn.close()
        print "Error while creating the service."
        return
    else:
        data = response.json()
```